# Sorting an array with bubble sort in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

```
array = [4, 7, 2, 1]

sorted = false

until sorted == true
  swapped = false

  array.each_with_index do |x, i|
    if i <= array.length - 2
      if array[i] > array[i + 1]
        array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end

    if swapped == false
      sorted = true
    end
  end
end

print array
```

Hello, I am trying to use bubble sort to sort an array of numbers. But it doesn't get sorted. Could someone help me to achieve that and point where my mistakes are?

Comment: @axiac I have changed `unless` to `until`, however I realised that if I change the numbers in my array, the code wouldn't work. Previously array = [4,3,2,1], now array = [4,7,2,1]

Comment: @sawa I have edited the question, hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: The `if swapped == false` block must stay after the `array.each`.

Comment: "I am unable to do it" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (original) code has two major issues:

- The main block should repeat **until** the list is sorted. You are using<sup>1</sup> `unless sorted == true` and this makes it run only once; you have to change it to `until sorted == true`;
- The check for `swapped == false` must stay **after** `array.each`. It's purpose is to signal the array is sorted (and end the loop) when no swapped was done after the list was analyzed again.

---

<sup>1</sup> The OP has edited the question in the meantime, after I suggested this correction in a comment.

The fixed code:

```
array = [4,7,2,1]

sorted = false
until sorted == true
  swapped = false
  array.each_with_index do |x,i|
    if i <= array.length - 2
      if array[i] > array[i+1]
        array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  end
  if swapped == false
    sorted = true
  end
end

print array
```

A lot of things are not in the spirit of Ruby in this piece of code. I'm not experienced in Ruby but I can suggest you a couple of improvements for it.

```
# Enclose the code into a function, for easier reuse.
def bubble_sort(array)
  sorted = false
  # "sorted" is boolean; there is no need to compare it with true or false
  until sorted
    swapped = false
    array.each_with_index do |x,i|
      # exit the loop when the last item is reached
      break if i == array.length - 1

      if array[i] > array[i+1]
        array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    # Boolean logic: it's sorted when no more items were swapped
    sorted = ! swapped
  end
  # Return the updated array
  array
end

print bubble_sort [4, 7, 2, 1]
```

@danil-speransky just provided a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45796577/4265352) that looks more like Ruby than mine.

Comment: Hi, why is it the check for `swapped = false` under the `array.each` wouldn't be able to signal to the array that it is sorted (and end the loop) while `swapped = false` situated after `array.each` will be able to signal to end the loop? How I understand is that both ways are ultimately setting `sorted =true` which will then result in ending the loop. How does the order of the code for `swapped == false`(in `array.each` and after `array.each) come into play here? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: The array is sorted if, after the entire `each` block runs, no swapping was performed. Inside the `each` loop, `swapped` is `false` until it founds the first pair of values that are in the wrong order. If you want to sort `[1, 2, 7, 4]`, the first iteration of `each` compares `1` to `2`, they are in the correct order and `swapped` is not set to `true`. If you checking its value inside the `each` block, `sorted` is set to `true` after the comparison of `1` and `2`, i.e. it reaches the wrong conclusion that the list is sorted without even checking all its items.

Comment: However I am puzzled that for `[1,2,7,4]`, after being "sorted" using my wrong code it somehow return [1,2,4,7] which is the desired order.

Comment: For `[1,2,7,4]` your code runs the `until` loop only once. When it compares `1` to `2` it incorrectly sets `sorted` to `true`. `2` and `7` are also in the correct order. `7` and `4` are swapped then it exits the `until` loop. The array is sorted now but the correct algorithm requires an additional iteration of the `until` loop to detect that. Print the values of `array`, `sorted`, `swapped`, `i` etc on each iteration (both `until` and `each`) and see how it works. Or use a debugger to run the program one step at a time and inspect the content of the variables.

Comment: Please kindly bear with me, why is it that the code runs the `until` loop only once? I have not learn how to use a debugger yet but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: The best way to understand what happens inside the code (even without a debugger) is to add code to print the values of the variables everywhere you feel you need (usually after the code blocks that could change them), run the program, check what the debug code you just added prints and simulate (using pencil and paper) what happens with the data step by step.

Comment: Hi. I took your advice and I finally got it. So much gratitude to you and I really appreciate you answering my question :)

Answer (score 1):

You should place the piece below after the loop, because you want to stop if you have no swaps after iterating through the array.

```
if swapped == false
  sorted = true
end
```

You also may want to get rid of unnecessary `sorted` using `break`. Here is my variant:

```
array = [4, 7, 2, 1]

loop do
  swapped = false

  (array.length - 1).times do |i|
    if array[i] > array[i + 1]
      array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
      swapped = true
    end
  end

  break unless swapped
end

print array
```